# RSS <link> tag not appearing in <head> of Drupal view page display output

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6 site with a view that has a page and a feed display. Both the page and the feed work great. The view just shows content type Story in reverse chronological order- basic blog listing page.

While the RSS look good, the page display doesn't include the  tag in the header for auto-discovery. I've outputting $head in my page.tpl.php, so it should be there. Also, I noticed the $feed_icons variable is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 6 this is no longer automatic.

Edit the view and under "Feed Settings" set "Attach to" to the page that you want to autodiscover the feed.

Answer (score 1):

This should happen automatically in most cases. If you are doing something a little strange you may need to use [drupal_add_feed()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_feed/6) to add the feed to the page